Preservation of algebraic independence
Take linear independence as an example: If $S$ is a set of vectors in some vector space $V$ and $A$ is a linear automorphism of $V$, then $S$ is linearly independent if and only if the set $AS$ of images under $A$ is linearly independent.
How does this go for algebraic independence? Let $K/L$ be a field extension and $S \subseteq K$ be a set. I'm not sure what to take instead of linear automorphism. Probably, the following does: let $(b_i)_{i \in I}$ be a transcendence basis of $K/L$, and $B$ be a transformation $B\colon K \to K$, $b_i \mapsto f_i$, where $f_i$ is a polynomial in $b_i$'s with property X.
Question: Is it then true that $S$ is algebraically independent if and only if $B(S)$ is, and what is the property X $B$ has to have for this to become true?
Additional question: Say $M$ is a matrix of which a certain subset of entries is algebraically independent. Say $A$ is an invertible $K$-matrix. Under what circumstances can I link algebraic independence of these entries of $M$ to the algebraic independence of some set of entries of $MA$?

I don't know if I understood coorrectly. If you have a non trivial ring homomorphism $B\colon L\to L$ sending $K$ to itself, then $S$ is a set of algebraic independent set over $K$ if and only if $BS$ is an algebraic independent set over $K$.
Indeed, since $B$ is a homomorphism of fields, then $B$ is forced to being injective, and so  given $s_1, \dots, s_n\in S$ we have
$$p(s_1,\dots, s_n)=0 \iff B(p(s_1,\dots, s_n))=0 \iff p(Bs_1,\dots, Bs_n)=0.$$
for each polynomial $p$ with coefficient in $K$. Hence $s_1, \dots ,s_n$ does not vanish on $p$ if and only if $Bs_1, \dotsm Bs_n$ does not vanish on $p$, which means $S$ is algebraic independent if and only if $BS$ is algebraic independent.
Is this what you asked or maybe I am missing something?

You need $B$ to fix $K$. Then $B(p(s_1,\dots, s_n))=p(Bs_1,\dots, Bs_n)$.

Thank you, you are definitely right

Indeed, I was missing that $B$ needs to be injective if it is a ring homomorphism. Which brings me to the followup question: How do I know if $L(x_1,\dotsc,x_n) \to L(x_1, \dotsc, x_n), x_i \mapsto \frac{p_i(x_1,\dotsc, x_n)}{q_i(x_1,\dotsc, x_n)}$ is a ring homomorphism?

What is for you $L(x_1,\dots ,x_n)$?

@FedericoFallucca The field of rational functions in the variables $x_1,\dotsc,x_n$ with coefficients in $L$.
